# При выборке из двух таблиц получаю один и тот же `username`?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite, mysqli

Есть две таблицы в [SQLite файле](https://yadi.sk/d/ZgJZikU5KFj9rg):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю такой запрос, с любыми значениями для author_id и interlocutor_id, например соответственно 1 и 3:

```
posts = db.execute(
    'SELECT p.id, author_id, interlocutor_id, msg, created, u.username'
    ' FROM post p JOIN user u'
    ' ON author_id = ?'
    ' AND interlocutor_id = ?'
    ' OR interlocutor_id = ?'
    ' AND author_id = ?'
    ' ORDER BY p.created DESC',
    (main_id, user_id, main_id, user_id,)
).fetchall()
for i in posts:
    pst[i['id']] = i['username']
```

Перебирая результат, создаю словарь, и почему-то всегда в username попадает только пользователь root. А я ожидаю получить разных, в зависимости от переданных id. Прошу объяснить, что я не так делаю?

На выходе я хочу получить словарь, пока простой - `{id_поста: username(автор поста) }` , если это получится, то добавлю и текст поста `msg`.

Comment: Попробуйте со скобками: `(author_id = ? AND interlocutor_id = ?) OR (interlocutor_id = ? AND author_id = ?)`

Comment: MaxU, не меняется результат, к сожалению, все так же получаю значение root

Comment: можете выложить ваши SQLite файлы на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: Да, конечно, вот по этой ссылке https://yadi.sk/d/ZgJZikU5KFj9rg

Comment: а что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: На выходе я хочу получить словарь, пока простой  - {id_поста: username(автор поста) } , если это получится, то добавлю и текст поста msg. Сейчас могу получить id и msg, это полчается. Но если вывожу username, то стабильно выдает root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas

conn = sqlite3.connect(r'D:\download\flaskr.sqlite')

qry = """
SELECT p.id, author_id, interlocutor_id, msg, created, u.username
FROM post p
JOIN user u
  ON u.id = p.author_id
WHERE (p.author_id = ? AND p.interlocutor_id = ?)
       OR
      (p.interlocutor_id = ? AND p.author_id = ?)
ORDER BY p.created DESC"""

data = pd.read_sql(qry, conn, params=(1,3,1,3))
```

результат в виде pandas.DataFrame:

```
In [100]: data
Out[100]:
   id  author_id  interlocutor_id      msg              created username
0  19          1                3  Привет!  2018-12-15 15:33:53     root
1  18          1                3  Привет!  2018-12-15 15:33:48     root
2  15          3                1      ddd  2018-12-15 15:31:10  hamidmi
```

результат в виде словаря:

```
In [101]: data.to_dict('record')
Out[101]:
[{'id': 19,
  'author_id': 1,
  'interlocutor_id': 3,
  'msg': 'Привет!',
  'created': '2018-12-15 15:33:53',
  'username': 'root'},
 {'id': 18,
  'author_id': 1,
  'interlocutor_id': 3,
  'msg': 'Привет!',
  'created': '2018-12-15 15:33:48',
  'username': 'root'},
 {'id': 15,
  'author_id': 3,
  'interlocutor_id': 1,
  'msg': 'ddd',
  'created': '2018-12-15 15:31:10',
  'username': 'hamidmi'}]
```

Comment: MaxU, спасибо Вам большое, заработало!